# Monitor JMX with Nagios for space on name

Tags: nagios, nrpe, jmx

We are trying to monitor JMX with Nagios XI and using check_jmx Plugin. Its working fine for Heap memory, thread count etc..We re facing issue on while using the following:

```
obj": "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Par Eden Space",
"attr": [
"Usage"] ],

"obj": "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep",
attributes: [CollectionCount,
CollectionTime]
```

We tried varios options but as there is space in name its no getting. SO can anyon ehelp how we can specify name with spaces.

```
check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9199/jmxrmi -O java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name='PS MarkSweep' -A CollectionCount -K duration -u ms -vvvv -w 10 -c 10


JMX CRITICAL java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS connecting to java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS by URL service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9199/jmxrmijavax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS
```

Can any one please help us.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by applying the following [patch](https://github.com/tcurdt/nagios-check-jmx/issues/1) in which we added quotes for $@ on file check_jmx